# Teamcity triggers build in feature branch after changes in master

Tags: teamcity

I currently have the issue that Teamcity triggers a build in my feature branch after a commit/PR merged in master.

A bit more context:
I have a repository in GitHub, I have linked it correctly to Teamcity. I have set the trigger for VCS to look at /api directory inside the repo.
I tick the setting on “exclude default branch changes from other branches”.
I create a PR from master, do a couple of changes in /api, they get picked up, that’s great.
I create another PR, do a few changes, then push it to master.
Then, my initial feature branch gets retriggered.

Is there a reason this is happening? I do not want the behaviour and I thought the setting would take that off. Ideally, I want my build to only be triggered when I push a change to the feature branch (and it builds the feature branch) or master branch (and it only builds the master branch).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to define spec in VCS Root settings of your repo.

If you need to build just `master` branch use only

```
+:/refs/heads/master
```